# Maintain consistent PostgreSQL array column indices while concatenating array columns when dealing with empty column values

Tags: arrays, postgresql, join, null

Given the following starting data:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 AS
  SELECT generate_series(1, 20) AS id,
    (SELECT array_agg(generate_series) FROM generate_series(1, 6)) as array_1;

CREATE TABLE t2 AS
  SELECT generate_series(5, 10) AS id,
    (SELECT array_agg(generate_series) FROM generate_series(7, 10)) as array_2;

CREATE TABLE t3 AS
  SELECT generate_series(8, 15) AS id,
    (SELECT array_agg(generate_series) FROM generate_series(11, 15)) as array_3;
```

I would like to do an outer join between several tables, each with a fixed-length array column that is uniform within a given table, but may differ from table to table (as in the examples above), concatenating the array columns in each table into one large array column. I was wondering if there is an efficient or straightforward way to maintain consistent indexing in the new combined column, replacing `NULL` column values (caused by the outer join) with an array of `NULL` values so that the final array column will have a uniform length. Unlike in the above example, in my actual use case, I won't know the length of each table's array column *a priori*, only that it will be of a uniform length throughout that table. In other words, instead of this query:

```
SELECT id, (array_1 || array_2 || array_3 ) AS combined_array FROM
t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 USING(id) LEFT OUTER JOIN t3 USING (id);
```

Which produces:

```
id |            combined_array
----+---------------------------------------
 1 | {1,2,3,4,5,6}
 2 | {1,2,3,4,5,6}
 3 | {1,2,3,4,5,6}
 4 | {1,2,3,4,5,6}
 5 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
 6 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
 7 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
 8 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}
 9 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}
10 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}
11 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12,13,14,15}
12 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12,13,14,15}
13 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12,13,14,15}
14 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12,13,14,15}
15 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12,13,14,15}
16 | {1,2,3,4,5,6}
17 | {1,2,3,4,5,6}
18 | {1,2,3,4,5,6}
19 | {1,2,3,4,5,6}
20 | {1,2,3,4,5,6}
(20 rows)
```

I would like the result to look like:

```
id |            combined_array
----+---------------------------------------
 1 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL}
 2 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL}
 3 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL}
 4 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL}
 5 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL}
 6 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL}
 7 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL}
 8 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}
 9 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}
10 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}
11 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,11,12,13,14,15}
12 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,11,12,13,14,15}
13 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,11,12,13,14,15}
14 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,11,12,13,14,15}
15 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,11,12,13,14,15}
16 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL}
17 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL}
18 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL}
19 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL}
20 | {1,2,3,4,5,6,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL}
(20 rows)
```

So that each row contains an array of length 15.

Comment: n-length? Can each row have a different length? Do you take biggest value then? If so what to do with shorter rows?

Comment: Sorry, my description is somewhat confusing. Each table will have an array column with a uniform length throughout that table, but I don't necessarily know the length of the array for a particular table a priori if that makes sense. So table one may have an array column of length 10 and table 2 might have an array column of length 3. In my use case, I can't hard code these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, here is the query that I came up with that appears to do the job. It doesn't seem particularly elegant or efficient to me so definitely still open to other answers.

```
SELECT id, (
  coalesce(array_1, array_fill(NULL::INT,
    ARRAY[(SELECT max(array_length(array_1, 1)) FROM t1)])) ||
  coalesce(array_2, array_fill(NULL::INT,
    ARRAY[(SELECT max(array_length(array_2, 1)) FROM t2)])) ||
  coalesce(array_3, array_fill(NULL::INT,
    ARRAY[(SELECT max(array_length(array_3, 1)) FROM t3)]))
) AS combined_array FROM
t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 USING(id) LEFT OUTER JOIN t3 USING (id);
```